# Correct hypotesis test for showing multiple temperature profiles are the same

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have data from an experiment where I heated 3 different objects. During the experiment I measured the temperature inside all 3 objects at 3 different depths from the heat source (but the same 3 depths for all the objects). I plotted the temperature profiles for each object at a relevant time and I want to see (and prove), with an hypotesis test, that the profiles are equal for the three objects. My question is if this is possible and significant with this amount of data, and if so, which is the best test for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove that means are exactly equal. You can, however, establish with specified confidence that two means do not differ by more than a specified threshold $\tau$, using an equivalence test. A common method is the "two one-sided test" (TOST) procedure of Schuirmann. One way to describe that procedure is to construct a $1 - 2\alpha$ confidence interval for the difference of means. If that interval lies entirely within the interval $(-\tau,+\tau)$, then you reject the null hypothesis of non-equivalence with significance level $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would this kind of test also be appropriate for comparison between real test data and data obtained from simulations in the same mode as described in the question?

Comment: Maybe, but maybe not. If the simulations are based on the observed estimated means, I'd say NOT, because you'd be answering a moot question. BTW, you should specify the value of \tau based entirely on subject-matter considerations -- and before looking at the data. For example, choose a threshold of 10 degrees because you and your colleagues agree that a temperature difference less than that has no practical significance.

Comment: The simulations would be based on a model created independently of the test data, by another researcher. About the tau value, this is good to hear, because we are in a field where too much precision is not relevant. Something that just came by now... the temperature measurements occur in each object in the same depths, wouldn't this be a paired samples instead of independent samples?

Comment: In fact, this is because the different depths generate very different temperatures, for example, depth 1: 500°C; depth 2: 200°C. So, do I really should compare the means of these very different measurements?

Comment: My answer just describes the principles behind equivalence testing. Obviously, you need to apply those principles in the context of an appropriate model. An no, it does not make sense to test equivalence of things you don't think should be equivalent. I was thinking you do those tests separately at each depth. Perhaps you want to expand your question or author a new one with a dataset - either the real one or some toy dataset with similar structure.

Comment: Thanks very much, i'll study these tests and see what is more appropriate.